# javascript error on tagger autocomplete EE3

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-tagger, tagger

After an upgrade to EE3 using Tagger 4 by DevDemon, I'm getting javascript errors in the console when Tagger is trying to autocomplete/suggest a tag to use.
The error is:

```
https://domain.com/undefined&ajax_method=tag_search?term=paint
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The tagger uses Ajax to call the autocomplete function which was getting the wrong url in **tagger_pbf.js** file on **/themes/user/tagger/** path.

> We have updated line 22 and 36 to set Tagger.ACT_URL with Tagger.AJAX_URL.

Autocomplete suggestions are working fine for me now.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.